# Create an app only for the homepage in Django?

Tags: python, django

The rest of the apps do not seem relevant enough to make use one of their views as the main homepage.

Is it a bad practice to create an app only for the homepage?

What is the best practice for the homepage when developing in Django? Or at least the most common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really if it's a bad practice or not since as you said other functionality is not relevant but for sure it's a lot of work for just showing homepage, but you can do  tho if it's just rendering Html template with just js and CSS you can use `.as_view()` function that Django provides (if it does not get any data from your backend)